# After installing Kubuntu 22.04 from DVD it do not start from Harddisk

Tags: boot, kubuntu, uefi

I've installed Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS from DVD burned from the downloaded ISO image.

The Live DVD started normally, the installation procedure was completed without error. I've selected the the default partitioning. After the installation was completed, the DVD was ejected and the computer restarted, but it do not find a bootable operating system.

I booted a gparted CD and I see that there are the followoing partitions:

```
/dev/sda1  unknown                           1 MB bios_grub
/dev/sda2  FAT32     EFI System partition  513 MB boot.esp
/dev/sda3  ext4                            931 GB
```

**May be that my laptop (Fujitsu Lifebook A351) is not compatible with EFI?** I had previously Kubuntu 18.04 (upgraded from Kubuntu 16) on the same machine without any problem.

Comment: The Fujitsu Lifebook A351 has a 10th or 11th gen intel processor from what I'm seeing online. Is that correct? It should be able to boot from EFI if it's that new. Does your bios have a setting for EFI booting enabled? Does it have Secure Boot enabled? Can you describe what you are seeing in more detail when you boot up and the OS isn't loaded? Similar question asked here: https://askubuntu.com/q/921857/288083

Comment: Here is a good explanation that may help as you go forward: https://askubuntu.com/a/1460499/288083

Comment: @NuclearPeon Yes, I thought also that my laptop can boot from EFI. But the "Secure Boot" setting in BIOS is not available. At the and I installed a minimal Ubuntu 16 and upgraded it step by step with do-release-upgrade to Ubuntu 22. It worked perfectly.

Comment: It could have been a DVD burning issue. If you have a USB to boot from, using Rufus with EFI mode is my go-to for installing Linux. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @NuclearPeon It was not a DVD burning issue, I've checked the checksum. But I could apply the workaround described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought also that my laptop can boot from EFI, but the "Secure Boot" setting in BIOS mentioned on Fujitsu's support pages is not available.

At the and I've installed a minimal Ubuntu 16 and upgraded it step by step with

> do-release-upgrade

to Ubuntu 22. It worked perfectly, the boot procedure was not changed by the release upgrades.